# How can I add extra parameter to URL when click "apply" button of Views exposed filter?

Tags: 6, views

I need to add extra parameter at the end of the page view URL when "apply" button of exposed filter is clicked.

For example,

normally URL looks like:

```
my-view?nid=1
```

But I need to add `"my_parameter=1"` at the end of the URL and it eventually needs to be:

```
my-view?nid=1&my_parameter=1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to add a [hidden form element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#hidden) with the value that you want (1 in your example). You'll have to check the View name and display name to ensure you only affect the right exposed filter.